# Parse single list into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

Problem: I need to run the same API for several date ranges and append them all to a dataframe. My for loop appends each API call's dataframe as a list. I'm hoping to parse the list into columns like the API call typically returns and append them all together.

```
earnings_info = []
for earnings_api in earnings_df['earnings_api']:
   response = requests.get(earnings_api, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'})
   df = json_normalize(response.json())
   earnings_info.append(df)
   sleep(1) 

earnings = pd.DataFrame(earnings_info)
```

This is the top of the output I'm receiving [image: Current Output]

This is the output of a single API call without the for loop and what I'm expecting the output to be [image: Expected Output]

Comment: can you show the output format of your API

Comment: The bottom picture is the expected output format of the API

Comment: What does the get api call returns?

Comment: You probably want to store the column names once, then use `earnings_info.append(df.values.tolist())`, then supply the column names when you create the consolidated DataFrame. You are reusing the `earnings_df` variable ... is that intended?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Because there's a limit on the date range allowed on the API call I need to run several in order to get the necessary information. I was kinda hoping the loop would just create a dataframe similar to running 1 call (shown in below picture) and keep appending but clearly not the case. Thanks for both of your help. Will give earnings_info.append(df.values.tolist()) a shot.

Comment: @DS_London This suggestion got me much further but when I create the consolidated data frame each invididual row becomes its own column and each of the API calls are the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DS_London I was able to parse the different rows for each of the API calls. However, when I consolidate the list into a dataframe each of the rows is given its own column and the different API calls are given different rows. Shown here:[image: example]

Hoping to transpose the data so that it looks similar to the bottom picture in the original post.

EDIT: Below is the layout of the single frame returned

[image: Single Frame Format]

Comment: What is the layout of the single frame returned from json_normalize?

Comment: added an edit above so I can add a picture

Comment: I think your original code was quite close. Change the last line to earnings = pd.concat(earnings_info, ignore_index=True)

Comment: Dude I got it !! Thank you so much this was giving me such hassle. We are all so lucky to have people like you. Thanks again.